# import gensim fails since updating to Xcode 7.3

Tags: python, c++, xcode, gensim

I just updated my version of Xcode to 7.3. When I run `pip install --upgrade gensim` the process completed without any issues. However, when I try import gensim within the python shell the terminal bars a bunch of C++ output with a block of execution errors that begins with:

`Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): clang: error: unsupported option '-b mi2'. clang: error: unsupported option '-b mi'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-sse4a'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-tbm'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'....`

I think this has something to do with where gensim is looking for its header files, but I'm somewhat at a loss. Any help debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't anticipate that problems I was having in gensim would ultimately be related to theano, but calling `import theano` reproduced the error. [Following the trace](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/696) from `import gensim` I identified that this is where the problem was. Here's the steps I followed to debug.

```
sudo pip uninstall theano
sudo pip uninstall gensim 
sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git #..install 'bleeding edge' theano from dev branch. this is the recommended fix for this issue that I've been seeing on the issue boards
sudo pip install --upgrade gensim
```